# Is it possible to clone a specific heroku version?

Tags: git, heroku, clone

I have several versions of a website on Heroku, I know for downloading I have to do:

```
heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

Can I download a specific version? Like v24?

Comment: What do you mean by *"version"*? Are you referring to git tags?

Comment: To know the version that you want to restore type   heroku release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have cloned the repo, you can reset or checkout any version you like.

To reset the branch to a particular commit, removing all commits above it, you can do:

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

To just checkout your code at a particular commit, you can do:

```
git checkout <commit-id>
```

I would suggest storing your code somewhere other than Heroku though. Heroku should only be used for deployment. You should give GitHub a try if you haven't already.